# WooCommerce: How to add product type next to product name in admin product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have created a new product type "`Crush Video Product`". It is saving all the meta fields correctly from its custom tab.

```php
// add a product type
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'crush_add_custom_product_type' );

function crush_add_custom_product_type( $types ){
    $types[ 'crush_video_product' ] = __( 'Group Video Class' );
    return $types;
}

// Initiate Class when plugin is loaded
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'crush_create_custom_product_type' );

function crush_create_custom_product_type(){
    // declare the product class

    class WC_Product_Crush_Video_Product extends WC_Product{
        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'crush_video_product';
            parent::__construct( $product );
            // add additional functions here
        }

        // Needed since Woocommerce version 3
        public function get_type() {
            return 'crush_video_product';
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have seen plugins where the name of the product type is written after the name of the product in the admin area where you can see all the products.

[image]

I searched a lot, but couldn't find a hook to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-products.php#L157-L203
>
> - Render column: name.

A more suitable hook seems to be missing, so one way is, use `manage_product_posts_custom_column`and if desired some CSS for the display

```php
function action_manage_product_posts_custom_column( $column, $postid ) {        
    if ( $column == 'name' ) {
        // Get product
        $product = wc_get_product( $postid );
        
        // Get type
        $product_type = $product->get_type();
        
        // Output
        echo '&nbsp;<span>&ndash; ' .  ucfirst( $product_type ) . '</span>';
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'action_manage_product_posts_custom_column', 20, 2 );
```

---

Result:

[image: Product type next to product name]